# How to compare two survival percentages for two different populations?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, survival, biostatistics

I calculated the 5 year survival of two populations keeping different variable constant each time and got percentages.
I wanted to determine if these percentages were significantly different from each other.
Could anyone please guide me with the same?